# How to redirect error to a Text file in VBS

Tags: vbscript

How to redirect Output to a Text file using vb script

I have a code like this

```
Dim tsIn
set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("E:\..t.csv") 'if file doesn't exist then error

 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description & "Input File Did not open" '> "E:\t.txt"
    Exit Sub
 End If
```

But how to redirect the error i get if a file doesn't exist in the folder?

i tried `>` but there's no result!

Comment: Do you want to send all outputs to a file or just few chosen messages?

Comment: only the error messages!

Comment: In that case, you have no other choice but to keep a text file open and send the output ... check my sample code below

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following

```
On Error Resume Next

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
errTxtFile = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\21777595.txt"
Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set FSO_Handle = objFSO.OpenTextFile (errTxtFile,8,True)

Err.Raise 6 'To test if the error is getting stored or not

 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    FSO_Handle.WriteLine Now & " - Error : " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect error to output.  %errorlevel% will still be 0 though.

```
cscript myscript.vbs > myscript.log 2>&1
```